# Slabs in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, case

I have done a slab from below query:

```
select slabs, count(student) from 
(select student,mark,
case when mark > 1 and <= 50 then 'fail'
when mark >50 and <=100 then 'pass'
else 'absent'
end slabs from table1) as table2
group by slabs
```

But I get an error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: <= integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Please help to solve this

Comment: did you try `case when mark > 1 and  mark  <= 50 then 'fail'
when mark >50 and mark <=100 then 'pass'`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it. I cannot use between function because I need exact values

Comment: You have a condition `<=50` which should be `mark<=50`; that's why Postgres is looking for a unary operator `<= integer`, rather than the binary operator `integer <= integer`.